# Progress reporting on dask's set_index

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to wrap a progress indicator around the entire script. However, `set_index(..., compute=False)` does still run tasks on the scheduler, observable in the web interface.

How do I report on the progress of the `set_index` step?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client, progress

if __name__ == '__main__':

  with Client() as client:

    df = dd.read_csv('big.csv')

    # I can see on the web interface that something is happening.
    # This blocks 20-30s on this particular CSV.
    df = df.set_index('id', compute=False)

    # Progress reporting works from here
    out = client.compute(
      df
    )
    progress(out)

    # out.result()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this. `set_index` eagerly [calls `compute` internally](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/dd636df4ba5e3bc63bd0f86e5a344966864d4539/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L40), because it needs to scan over your data to decide what the boundaries of the new partitions should be. There's no way to control this `compute` call and have it use a progress bar. If you think this would be worth exposing to users, you could [open an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues) to discuss it further.

Alternatively (the hard way), you could calculate the divisions of the DataFrame yourself (showing a progress bar while doing so), then pass them into `set_index`, to prevent `set_index` from doing the compute.

The downside here is you're replicating code that dask already has, and dask's method has some [extra](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/dd636df4ba5e3bc63bd0f86e5a344966864d4539/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L25-L70) [logic](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/dd636df4ba5e3bc63bd0f86e5a344966864d4539/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L185-L198) around repartitioning, detecting pre-sorted values and using a fastpath, etc. But in simple cases, something like this might work (note this is not using a public/documented API, so it could change without warning):

```py
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, progress

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Client() as client:

        df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

        # Calculate divisions manually to show a progress bar
        from dask.dataframe.partitionquantiles import partition_quantiles

        divisions_ddf = partition_quantiles(df["id"], df.npartitions)
        future = client.compute(divisions_ddf)
        print("Computing divisions")
        progress(future)
        divisions = future.result().tolist()

        df = df.set_index("id", divisions=divisions, compute=False)

        out = client.compute(df)
        progress(out)

        # out.result()
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dask.distributed` **progress** bar tracks the progress of futures. See docs [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html?highlight=progress#progress-bar).

Your `.compute` call is returning concrete results so there are actually no futures to track.

You can resolve this by using a `.persist()` call instead of `.compute()`.

**MCVE**

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd 
from dask.distributed import progress

ddf = dd.read_csv('big.csv')
result = ddf.set_index('id').persist()
progress(result)
```

[This article](https://coiled.io/blog/how-to-check-the-progress-of-dask-computations/) is a great resource for the different ways you can check progress on Dask computations.

FWIW there's a related open issue at Dask Distributed [here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3007)